# I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with my global variables in my python assignment

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I am having a problem with my python school assignment and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I either get a global name not defined or if I change things around I get different sythax errors. I am hoping that someone will be able to assist me in what I am doing wrong.

Here is a image of the assignment details:
[image]

```
def main():
  x = int(input("Give me integer #1: "))
  y = int(input("Give me integer #2: "))
  z = input("Give me a string: ")
  print("min:",min(x,y))
  print("max:",max(x,y))
  print("equal:",equal(x,y))
  print("is_even:",is_even(x))
  print("is_odd:",is_odd(x))
  print("format_dollar:",format_dollar(x))
  print("lab_grade:",lab_grade(x))
  print("is_unlucky:",is_unlucky(x))
  print("is_lucky:",is_lucky(x))
  print("pluralize:",pluralize(z)) 


#1 This function will figure out the min of 2 integer arguments and return the smaller one
def min(num1,num2):
    if num1 >= num2: return num1
    else: return num2

#2 This function will figure out the max of 2 integer arguments and return the smaller one
def max(num1,num2):
    if num1 <= num2: return num1
    else: return num2

#3 This function will figure out if the 2 numbers are equal
def equal(x,y):
    if x == y: True
    else: False

#4 This function will find out if the number is even
def is_even(num1,num2):
    is_even = x
    if x % 2 == 0: return ("True")
    else: return ("False")

#5 This function will find out if the number is odd
def is_odd(num1,num2):
    is_odd = x
    if x % 2 == 1: return ("True")
    else: return even

#6 This function will format the returned string
def format_dollar(num1,num2):
    x**('.2f')

#7 This function will fin out a lab grade
def lab_grade(x):
    lab_grade = int(raw_input("Enter the student's grade: "))
    if grade >= 90:
        return 'A'
    if grade >= 80:
        return 'B'
    if grade >= 70:

       return 'C'
    if grade >= 60:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'
#8 This will determine if the function is un_lucky
def is_unlucky(x):
    if x == 4:
        return ('True')
    if x == 13:
        return ('True')
    if x == 7:
        return ('True')
    else: ('False')
    print()


#9 This will determine if the function is lucky
def is_lucky(x):
    if x == 3:
        return ('True')
    if x == 4:
        return ('True')
    if x == 8:
        return ('True')
    if x == 7:
        return ('True')
    else:
        return ('False')


    print('')

#10 This function will pluralize
def pluralize(z):
    if not z:
        return plural
    print('')
main()
```

Comment: For one thing, you have functions trying to use a variable named `x` when they take parameters num1 and num2, but that's a lot of badly-formatted code to expect someone to go through.

Comment: One error is that in `main()`, you're trying to call functions that haven't been declared yet. You should declare functions before calling them, so all those print statements should go below the function definitions.

Comment: Here's a few things to get you started. You need to indent all the lines that are part of the `main()` function. When you run the program and it asks for a string, be sure to put quotes around whatever you enter. Your `even()` function is defined to take two numbers, but you only pass it one.

Comment: Your very first function -- `min` -- doesn't return the minimum.  I'd suggest working function by function while you learn Python syntax rather than trying to do them all at once.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: It's OK to call functions in a function _definition_ that haven't been defined yet.

Comment: @martineau http://codepad.org/ZW2Uqmxe, see the error here.

Comment: Okay I got the main function fixed so main isn't called at the end like I had it and I got all the blocks that only needed 1 integer down to that instead of having the 2 integers. Thanks

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: That's because in the code you linked you nested all the called function definitions inside the function that is calling them, so of course it doesn't work to call them before they are defined  -- this it not what (I think) the OP is doing.

Comment: In the future, you really should tell us where the error is, rather than making us read through all of the code and guess what might be wrong or get it running ourselves.

Comment: @Taylor Sand: Update your question if you're still having problems...or answer it yourself and accept the answer (when you can, you may not have the rep yet and you have to wait a certain amount of time).

Comment: Also, there are no global variables anywhere in this code, except by accident. All of your variables are either defined within functions (without the `global` modifier) or passed as parameters, so they should all be local. The only reason you get errors about globals is that you're trying to use variables that don't exist at all; when you say `is_odd = x` and there's no local called `x`, Python automatically goes looking for a global named `x`.

Comment: And finally, naming a local variable `is_odd` within a function named `is_odd` is just going to lead to confusion. Especially if you're learning multiple languages at once. Just don't do it; call the variable something else. (Or, in this case, you're not even using the variable, so you can just remove it.)

Answer (score 3):

Your `is_even()` and `is_odd()` functions look `evenly-odd`..

Well, that was just a joke.. Sorry.. But you are taking two different parameters `num1`, and `num2` whereas you are using a variable `x` getting assigned to an unknown variable `is_even` which I don't understand what is doing there??

Answer (score 0):

change even from:

```
def is_even(num1,num2):
    is_even = x
    if x % 2 == 0: return ("True")
    else: return ("False")
```

to:

```
def is_even(num1):
    if num1 % 2 == 0: 
        return ("True")
    else: 
        return ("False")
```

why?:

- You only need one input
- you shouldn't use the global x
- you shouldn't set is_even, a function, to a value.

is odd and format_dollar suffer from similar problems.

Comment: Thank you for that! Now I have a few less things to worry about but I am still getting my global variable error. Can you see a reason why? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say that what you did was write all 10 functions at one sitting then fired the whole mess up to see if it worked.  After the first half hour of banging your head against it you probably got to the point where you were just randomly changing things to see if by a miracle the smoke would clear.

Since this appears to be a very basic assignment I'll refrain from suggesting things like using test driven development, but you could make your life much easier by taking a more incremental approach.

First off start with your main and get it running so that all your function calls work without generating errors, something like:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Give me integer #1: "))
    y = int(input("Give me integer #2: "))
    z = input("Give me a string: ")
    print("min:", min(x, y))
    print("max:", max(x, y))
    print("equal:", equal(x, y))
    print("is_even:", is_even(x))
    print("is_odd:", is_odd(x))
    print("format_dollar:", format_dollar(x))
    print("lab_grade:", lab_grade(x))
    print("is_unlucky:", is_unlucky(x))
    print("is_lucky:", is_lucky(x))
    print("pluralize:", pluralize(z))

def min(x, y):
    return x

def max(x, y):
    return x

# Fill in all the other functions here in the same fashion.

main()
```

Do the same for all the functions, just return the first parameter passed in.  Once you get it so that your code runs without generating any errors.  Go function by function fixing each one to return the correct results.  A trick to make your life even easier is to hack main() (just for testing) to be:

```
def main():
    #x = int(input("Give me integer #1: "))
    #y = int(input("Give me integer #2: "))
    #z = input("Give me a string: ")
    x = 5
    y = 8
    z = 'foobar'

    print("min:", min(x, y))
    print("max:", max(x, y))
    print("equal:", equal(x, y))
    print("is_even:", is_even(x))
    print("is_odd:", is_odd(x))
    print("format_dollar:", format_dollar(x))
    print("lab_grade:", lab_grade(x))
    print("is_unlucky:", is_unlucky(x))
    print("is_lucky:", is_lucky(x))
    print("pluralize:", pluralize(z))
```

This way you can run your program quickly without having to enter input each time.  Once you get it working well, you can then remove the comments from in front of the inputs and remove your hard-coded values and turn it in with main() unchanged.

When returning True/False, you should use the actual Boolean values True and False, not their string representations.  Also as the assignment specifically called out elif, you should probably use if/elif/else statements rather than a bunch of discreet ifs as your code had.

```
#9 This will determine if the function is lucky
#  x = number to test
# returns True if number is lucky, else False
def is_lucky(x):
    if x == 3:
        return True
    elif x == 4:
        return True
    elif x == 8:
        return True
    elif x == 7:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```